# XAMPP Shell, stop php file with endless loop

Tags: php, shell, xampp

I have a file server.php for a WebSocket application. In this file is a endless loop. In order to run the WebSocket Server I need to run the file inside the XAMPP shell with "php -q server.php".

How can I stop that process inside the Shell? I dont want to close the commandline window every time and navigate to my server.php file when I reopen it.

Comment: CTRL+C in the same shell you launched the script would be the easiest option.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. :-(

Comment: Correction: It works in normal shell in Windows but not in the xampp shell.